# How to fix IO.File.ReadAllText not reading file

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing the file like this:

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\div.dat")

    objWriter.Write(data)
    objWriter.Close()
```

And reading it like this

```
Dim line As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Administrador\Documents\div.dat")
```

However line is simply empty, no error is returned, the file does exist, and I can open it with notepad and it has plain text inside.

Comment: Have you looked at `line` in the debugger *after* `ReadAllText` has been executed?

Comment: I think that this is a particularly good candidate for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, it looks fine, and we have to assume that the error is somewhere you have not shown us.

Comment: Open the file with notepad. if it is empty, "data" is probably empty too.

Comment: I would disagree with @sstan about the MCV of this code.  It fails to be either Complete or Verifiable.  Without knowing what the value of `data` is, what happens to the file between being written and being read, and how `line` is being interrogated its impossible to give a good answer.

Comment: @Sam Axe: Maybe I wasn't clear, but we're actually in agreement.  I am saying that this question is precisely the type that needs OP to provide us with the minimal, complete and verifiable example.  I'm not saying he has done so, I am saying he needs to.  Without that,there is nothing we can do for OP.

Comment: @sstan: ah.  my mistake.  It's easy to misinterpret perfectly valid English sentences. :)